# How to create this "dialog-like" popup in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a camera app and I want to do something similar to what the native camera app does for the Galaxy S3.  Here are some screenshots to give an idea of what I'm talking about.
[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape]

First of all, I don't think they are DialogFragments, because the screen behind it is not dimmed, and also they can be rotated (without the entire screen rotating). This is important to me, because I also am making a camera app which will be "locked" in portait, and have UI elements rotate themselves.

Does anyone know how to display an overlay like this for Android?  My first guess would be probably some sort of custom view implementation, but I'm not sure.

Comment: look this https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction

Comment: Interesting...that is about right.  Its annoying that there isnt anything more native like this